# How to convert a date string to a DateTime object in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a method that parse a date string

```
public static DateTime ParseDateTime(string dateString)
{
        DateTime dateTime;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out dateTime))
        {
            try
            {
                dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                ...
            }

        dateTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();
        return dateTime;
}
```

But in input I can have a different formats, for example if I change date format to `d/MM/yyyy`(Australia and United Kingdom locales) in my GUI then I will have 
`System.FormatException Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

How can I handle both of the situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of `Parse` and provide format string according to format you're using.

If you need to handle multiple formats at the same time, you can specify multiple formats in `formats[]` array.

Comment: Can you provide a code? I dont now how can I put multiple formats at the 
DateTime.ParseExact() method?

Comment: Have you had a look to the content of link I've posted? There is an example at the end of the article.

Comment: Yes, in MSDN all formats started with `M`, but United Kingdom locale is `d/MM/yyyy`. Where I can find list of all formats?

Comment: @Anatoly There are no such thing as "list of all possible formats" since you can construct format string by yourself using custom format specifiers. Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Can I have  DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal ?

Comment: It's up to you since I don't know if your date string contains timezone information or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact("2015-08-26 10:34:50,431", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff",                                                                                                
               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Check out [DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) for details.

Comment: But I dont now what type of input I will have (American or United Kingdom locales)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know the current culture, you can use this:

```
DateTime.Parse(dateString, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, false));
```

Answer (score 1):

That you need is to make use of `DateTime.ParseExact`. The following version:

```
public static DateTime ParseExact(
    string s,
    string[] formats,
    IFormatProvider provider,
    DateTimeStyles style
)
```

which

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent **using the specified array of formats**,
>   culture-specific format information, and style. The format of the
>   string representation must match at least one of the specified formats
>   exactly or an exception is thrown.

So, provided that you known exactly the possible formats of the dates, that user will enter you can catch them all with this method.
'
For a more detailed explanation of this method, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx)
.